# How to hide NVCC's "function was declared but never referenced" warnings?

Tags: cuda, googletest, nvcc

When compiling CUDA programs which use Google Test, `nvcc` will emit false-positive warnings:

> function <name> was declared but never referenced

An MCVE:

```
// test.cu
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace {

__global__ void a_kernel() {
    printf("Works");
}

TEST(ExampleTest, ExampleTestCase) {
    a_kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
}

}
```

Compiling it gives:

```
$ nvcc test.cu -lgtest -lgtest_main
test.cu(9): warning: function "<unnamed>::ExampleTest_ExampleTestCase_Test::ExampleTest_ExampleTestCase_Test()" was declared but never referenced
```

This is confirmed with the master branch of google test and CUDA 9.1 (I believe it started happening with CUDA 9.0, and the bug is not present in CUDA 8.0). The problem doesn't happen if the test is in the global namespace.

Is there a way to disable these warnings? I know I can use `-w` to disable **all** warnings, but I would like to keep other types of warnings.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but in case you need a solution for removing this warning and (a) don't mind changing a line in the gtest internals and (b) you can use c++11: go to [gtest-internal.h](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/1f605414cc4137f0ad0cde4d0c7366ff2dfac590/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h#L1257) and replace the `{}` by `= default;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the brute force way:

```
   #pragma push
   #pragma diag_suppress 177 // suppress "function was declared but never referenced warning"

   .. your function ..

   #pragma pop
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Fortunately, NVIDIA fixed the issue in CUDA 9.2, so there's no more false-positives, but it's still nice to have this for users with older compilers. Only, could you update the answer and explain where does this `177` code come from (i.e. how to find this code)? In case anyone looking at this question has a similar problem with a different kind of warning. I'll accept the answer then.

Comment: I'm glad you asked :) I spent quite some time trying to find this code for nvcc, and once I got frustrated by the lack of information, I wrote a script that generated a range of "diag_suppress" lines from 0 to 5000 or so, then manually binary searched for the correct code... I wish NVidia had the list of errors somewhere...

Comment: @MaximMakhinya I think the error codes depend on the frontend, here it is a list http://www.ssl.berkeley.edu/%7Ejimm/grizzly_docs/SSL/opt/intel/cc/9.0/lib/locale/en_US/mcpcom.msg , and here is a list with numeric codes: http://www.ece.ualberta.ca/~cmpe490/documents/ghs/405/c_error_ref.pdf . It looks like that your numeric code doesn't correspond to that particular warning, or perhaps the zero before the number is important.

Comment: @MaximMakhinya where do you get the number `177` from? Is there a table somewhere ?

Comment: @HuyLe please read the messages above, it already answers your question, I just binary searched all possible numbers...