# How to disable all unwanted nvcc compiler warnings

Tags: cuda, warnings, nvcc

I'm getting so many warnings at the `nvcc` compiler such as "was set but never used
", "was declared but never referenced", "expression has no effect" etc.  In one post, someone [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836419/how-to-hide-nvccs-function-was-declared-but-never-referenced-warnings) brute force `#prgma` for each warning. This is impractical because I have so many warnings. I tried `-w`, but that didn't work. In another post, someone [suggested](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/369566/cuda-programming-and-performance/disable-warnings/) `-Xcompiler "-w"` , but that didn't work for me either. How can I suppress all `nvcc` warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#generic-tool-options), `--disable-warnings` or `-w` will disable all nvcc (technically CUDA toolchain) generated warnings. As a rule, I counsel against ignoring compiler warnings. They exist for a reason.